# About maximal subfields of a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Given the division ring $D$ and a maximal subfield $K\subset D$, I'm trying to prove that $K=C_D(K)$, where $C_D(K)=\{d\in D:\forall k\in K, dk=kd\}$. In particular, I'm stuck in "$C_D(K)\subset K$". I found some notes where the argumentation is as follows:

*Let $a\in C_D(K)$ and let $T$ be the division ring generated by $K$ and $a$. Since $a$ commutes with all elements of $K$, $T$ is a field, then $K\subset T\subset D$ implying that $T=K$ with $a\in T=K$. Hence, $C_D(K)\subset K$.*

This argument is confusing for me because I don't see why $T$ results to be a field. I only know the following: Since $a$ commutes with all elements of $K$ the set $B=\{\sum_n ka^n:k\in K\}$ is an integral domain and it's possible to construct the field of fractions $\hat{B}$. I'm trying to see $\hat{B}$ as a subset of $D$ but I fail because the natural inclusion of $(a,b)\in\hat{B}$ via $ab^{-1}$ doesn't seen well-defined.

Is there a theorem that asure the existence of a subfield $T$ with $K\cup\{a\}\subset T\subset D$?

Comment: It's a division ring: $ab^{-1}$ does make sense.

Comment: If $(x,y)\sim (a,b)$ in $\hat{B}$, why $xy^{-1}=ab^{-1}$?

Comment: It's easier to stay within $D$. $T$ is defined to be the *division ring* generated by $K$ and $a$, so it also contains $a^{-1}$, and $x^{-1}$ whenever it contains $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: As you have noted, $K[a]$ is a commutative ring. It follows that for any nonzero $p,q\in K[a]$ you have $q/p=p\backslash q=q\cdot (1/p)=(1/p)\cdot q$. This can be used to show that the ring generated by $K[a]$ and the inverses of all its nonzero elements is still commutative. It follows that it is isomorphic to the field of fractions of $K[a]$ (so that in particular, it is a field).

Comment: Yeah, the fact that the inverse elements of $K[a]$ commutes between elements of $K[a]$ (for all $a,b\in K[a]$ we have $ab^{-1}=b^{-1}a$) is sufficient to prove that the field of fractions is in $D$  via the natural inclusion which is well-defined. Thanks.

Comment: @YesidFonsecaV.: If you are happy with my answer, you should accept it.